# How can I extract data from a website to excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping

I have been trying to get info from a website. After looking everywhere, I found the data I need, but I have no idea how I would extract that info. I am not looking for you to do the work, just to let me know  how I can do it. I have circled in blue what I need.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: your screenshot is showing the source html with the script calls that generate the page. That is not what Excel will see. If you want to scrape the data with Excel, your starting point needs to be the page as it is rendered in the browser. Excel can scrape data from some HTML constructs, like tables. If the data is rendered dynamically with Javascript, then it will not be visible to Excel for scraping.

Comment: Thanks ! That answers my question. Any other way than with excel to retrieve the info ?